# What are the correct permissions so WP doesn't ask for FTP credentials if installing plugin?

Tags: plugins, installation, permissions

My nginx user is www-data. If I do `su www-data` I can create both file and directory.

But when installing plugin I am asked for FTP credentials.

I tried to give the public_html directory 777 permissions for a while to test if I can install plugin without providing FTP credentials but it didn't help either.

- WP 3.2.1
- nginx
- ubuntu

How can I install plugins without providing FTP credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this in the wp-config.php, check the [Editing wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) page in the docs.

Comment: Yes, I can but I don't want to for reasons (security etc..)

Comment: @Radek if someone got as far as your `wp-config.php` - there is no security left to worry about.

Comment: @Rarst: you're right ... but when searching for answer before posting my question. I found above solution. And somebody mentioned security reasons why not to do so.

Comment: @Radek, it's better to add FTP credentials to the wp-config.php than to add it to your database (the fields you can fill in during the update process). When you paste them directly into the wp-config.php they're not send through POST like the default process (that's why it's safer).

Answer (score -1):

The owner of the files **must be php user**. To have php user in the group is not good enough.

Comment: What is 'php user'?

Comment: A user that php is running under.